# How to add pop up image when textview is click?

Tags: android

```
questions.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/footer" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/warning"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/q1a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/sas1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/q2a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sas2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/q3a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sas3"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>
```

how can i put a pop-up image whne i click the text view?

for example..i click the first textview, an image will appear for 2 or 3 seconds then it ill disappear and then when i will click the second text view another different image will appear for 2 or 3 seconds also..

question#1 = fever = then it will show an example image of fever
question#2 = skin rashes = then it will show example images of what skin rashes looks like.

note: nevermind the checkboxes..what's important is the textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can done as well (If I understand you well) By using Alert Dialog as in example below:

on your onCreate() activity main method or on TextView action listener, call this code, as **simple example**:

```
    ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    loadPhoto(image,100,100);
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
              ad.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
              t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
        }
    }, 5000); // after 5 second (or 5000 miliseconds), the task will be active.
```

which **loadPhoto** method:

```
   public void loadPhoto(ImageView imageView, int width, int height) {

   ImageView tempImageView = imageView;
   imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   imageDialog.setCancelable(true);
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog,
           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
   ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
   image.setImageDrawable(tempImageView.getDrawable());
   imageDialog.setView(layout);
   imageDialog.setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           dialog.dismiss();
       }

   });
   ad=imageDialog.create();
   ad.show();     
}
```

which **ad** variable declare in class as:

```
 public AlertDialog ad;
```

In where also the custom alert dialog **custom_fullimage_dialog** xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/fullimage" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ImageView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/custom_fullimage_placename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF">
</TextView>
```

**Imports**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: can you show me the imports and the variables that must be declared.? @Maheera

Comment: yes, for imports you just need to click (ctrl+shift+o) then all imports need will imports by eclipse... however, you can see the Edit code above. for variables to this code I write all of them BUT for your code you need to declare all Textview, checkbox, etc. which in xml on your Activity! Regards,

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly easy...

Implement the onClick Listeners for the `TextView`,  then show the images in a custom `AlertDialog` on click. By custom here I mean, add a custom view to the `AlertDialog` which will contain an `ImageView` to show your image.

Now using a `Runnable` dismiss the `AlertDialog` after few seconds.

Comment: can you show me the syntax of the code..i'm just a beginner in java eclipse @twntee